# Sending multiple Local Notifications in a period of time

Tags: swift, notifications, nsdate

I am building an app where the user puts in there working hours and working days. I need to be able to send the user a local notification every 20 minutes to update them on something. I am having trouble being able to add the exact date and times to `scheduleLocalNotification`. Would this be done by adding multiple fire dates? Or an array of dates?

Any input helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is good programming to only have one notification for one function at the time. So you raise a notification to fire at 14:00h.
In the fired selector you can create a new notification for 14:30h.

However when you want to have the notifications at scheduled periods you can use the repeat = YES for the Timer notification.